# How to get absolute path of file depends on windows 32-bit or 64-bit machine

Tags: java

I am trying to get absolute file path on java, when i use the following code :

```
File f = new File("..\\webapps\\demoproject\\files\\demo.pdf")  
String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

It gives the correct file path on 32-bit machine as

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin\..\webapps\demoproject\files\demo.pdf
```

But when i run the same on 64-bit machine it gives FileNotFound Exception (because of Program Files(x86)), How to get correct path regardless of OS bit. Could anybody please help.

Comment: The file is created using current working directory. It is not a function of operating system. Could you create the file with absolute path?

Comment: actually i have deployed demoproject.war inside of webapps, where tomcat is installed inside Program Files in 32-bit and inside Program Files(x86) in 64-bit, when i am giving absolute path it is working on 32-bit but same FileNotFound Exception on 64-bit

Comment: And when you try to access `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin\..\webapps\demoproject\files\demo.pdf` this works fine.

Comment: @peter : it doesn't work

Comment: If it doesn't work outside Java, it won't work inside Java.  What path does it need to be?

Comment: i have written code in 32-bit so its always take `C:\Program Files..` either i run on 32-bit or 64-bit, it doesn't change according to OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used below code and it is giving correct file path where i have used
`System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the current working directory and `System.getenv("ProgramFiles")` to check program files name.

`

```
    String downloadDir = "..\\webapps\\demoproject\\files";

    String currentdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String programFiles = System.getenv("ProgramFiles");

    String filePath = "";
    if(programFiles.equals("C:\\Program Files"))
    {
        filePath = currentdir + "\\" + downloadDir + "\\demo.pdf";
    }
    else
    {
        filePath = currentdir + "\\" + "bin"+ "\\" + downloadDir + "demo.pdf";
    }

    File pdfFile = new File(filePath);
    String absolutePath = pdfFile.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(absolutePath);
```

`
After executing below code i am getting the following path-

**On 32-bit**
`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin\..\webapps\demoproject\files\demo.pdf`

**On 64-bit**
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin\..\webapps\demoproject\files\demo.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of your concern.

Just give a try to:

`request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`

It will give you the context path of your application Root folder regardless of underlying platform and you can add required folder or file's relative path (Relative path from application root folder ) with it to get absolute path.